# AS3 - Simple Login

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, authentication

I want to make a really simple login system in AS3. The process is easy. If the name&password are correct, the flash will go to another frame.

```
login.btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, loginFunction)
function loginFunction (Event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (loginname_input.text == "Name" && loginpassword_input.text == "Password"){
        gotoAndStop(xy);
    } else {
        loginerror_text.visible = true;
    }
}
```

I tried everything. There's no proble, but if I use the correct name and pass, it uses the 'else' command. Any idea?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You are sure you don't have typos in your script? `trace` both values when you trigger the `loginFunction` and see what they really are. Maybe a whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a lot of tutorials of logins. Everyone uses different Layers for buttons,inputs etc. this matter? Because I'm only use 2 layers. One for Actions, and one for the inputs, bg, and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your loginname_input.text and loginpassword_input.text to "" (empty string) before the user enters the login information. I find textfields on the stage sometimes inexplicably have whitespace/hard return automatically inserted, which will mess up your if statement.